# How to get current post user id

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, users

I have some posts, each post have different authors(users).
I save each author image avatar in **user_meta** table. 
Now i want show each author avatar in self posts. i get **user_id** with **wp_get_current_user()** function. but it work when user is logged in, i want when user not logged in get user id and show user avatar

Here my code

first way show user post avatar to all post not work
    $current_user = $post->post_author;

```
  <?php if (!empty(get_user_meta($current_user, 'user_avatar', true))): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user, 'user_avatar', true); ?>" alt="some text">
```

Second way work, but whene user is logged in

```
$current_user = wp_get_currebt_user();

  <?php if (!empty(get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_avatar', true))): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_avatar', true); ?>" alt="some text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show author avatar per post inside loop you need to modify a little:

```
$current_post_author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
<?php if (!empty(get_user_meta($current_post_author_id, 'user_avatar', true))): ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_user_meta($current_post_author_id, 'user_avatar', true); ?>" alt="some text">
```

Try, if it works for you.